# Hiding a <br> element using CSS [attribute="value"] selector

Tags: css-selectors, hide

I'm trying to hide a `<br>` using CSS alone:

```css
br[some-label="1"] {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Paragraph 1 with non-hidden
  <br> br
</p>
<p>
  Paragraph 2 with hidden
  <br some-label="1"> br
</p>
```

I have also tried `.p + br[some-label="1"]{...}`.

Unfortunately, I only have limited control over the HTML and so can't add labels, id, classes etc to the elements to hide them.

Any suggestions on a way to hide the `<br>` element with a particular attribute value would be appreciated.

Comment: I've edited the question to illustrate that the code provided does work. There are details left out that must be included in order for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Much clearer. Thanks.